# Can't get Subclipse to run on CentOS workstation

Tags: eclipse, centos, subclipse

I'm running Eclipse under CentOS, and would like to use Subclipse rather than keep having to muck about with SVN via the command line.  Unfortunately, I can't get the thing to run.

It installs, but when I try to import a repository, I get "Error validating location:  'Unable to load default SVN Client'".  I've searched for this on-line, and it seems to indicate that JavaHL isn't available.  ([This FAQ](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL) seems pretty representative.)

The computer in question is my workstation at work, and I don't have complete administrative control over it; installing the CollabNet SVN isn't really an option.  Now, one of the (very cooperative) sysadmins did make JavaHL (1.6.15-1) available via `yum`, and it installed just fine -- it put svn-javahl.jar in /usr/lib/svn-javahl, and libsvnjavahl-1.so in /usr/lib.  It seems I'm supposed to update eclipse.ini to point to these new files via `-Djava.library.path=` entries beneath `-vmargs`, but nothing I enter seems to matter.  I've tried `/usr/lib/svn-javahl/`, `/usr/lib/svn-javahl/svn-javahl.jar`, `/usr/lib/`, all to no avail.  I've confirmed via `Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration` that my edits to eclipse.ini are indeed getting picked up.

I've confirmed the JavaHL version (1.6.x) matches my Subclipse version (1.6.17).

Does anybody have any advice for other stuff I ought to be trying?

Comment: Open the preferences page for Subclipse. What does it say there?

Comment: Well, I don't see a page for Subclipse; the closest I see is Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN.  If that's the page you're referring to, what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the JavaHL JAR file.  Subclipse includes the Java code.  You just need to configure Java so that the native libraries are found.  Given that they are probably in /usr/lib you may not need to anything. But if there is anything to do it would be:

-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib

However, if the drop-down in the preferences is empty, you have bigger problems.  That means that either the JavaHL and SVNKit client adapters are not installed (most likely) or they are failing to load for some reason.  Because they should appear in the drop-down if the plugins are installed.  The JavaHL line would just say something (Not installed) if the native library was not available.  And since SVNKit is pure Java, if it is installed it always shows up fine.

So I think you should be looking in that direction.  I do not think you could have the client adapter plugins installed from the Subclipse update site.

Comment: Bingo!  I thought I had Subclipse fully installed, but I was apparently mistaken.  Once I re-installed everything, it worked right away.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The preferences page for Subclipse contains a field where you can select the client adapter. It shows the error message there when the adapter can't be loaded.

If that fails, find the "svnkit" adapter and install that. It's a pure Java implementation of the SVN protocol.

Comment: I see a "Client" pull-down menu in the "SVN interface:" section of Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN; is that what you're referring to?  It doesn't show anything -- it's an empty pull-down.

Comment: Also, installing "svnkit" didn't appear to do anything by itself -- I still have the same problem, and nothing seems to have changed.  Is there something I need to configure before svnkit will show up?

Comment: Yes, the "client" pull down shows all available clients. If it's empty, then you have no client adapters installed. Seems your install is broken somehow. Even when Eclipse can't load the javahl DLL, it should at least show the adapter.